# SQL Server restore query works in Management Studio but does not work in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, restore

I have a problem when trying to do restore against a database using C#. It throws timeout error in C#, but works fine in SQL Server Management Studio.

I've been googling around, and no luck so far fixing this problem. Also the similar problem here does not apply to my case...

The SQL Server version is 2008 R2 (10.50).

Things I've tried:

- increase connection timeout
- increase commandTimeout

no luck on either

Here is the query:

```
DECLARE @ResultCode INT   

EXEC @ResultCode = [master].[dbo].[xp_ss_restore] @database = 'KbbVehicle',@filename = 
'\\P02W02ETLDZZ017\Staging\MasterBackups\KbbVehicle.safe',
@server = 'p02w02etldzz017',@disconnectusers = 1, @replace = 1 

SELECT @ResultCode AS ResultCode
```

and here is the exception and stack trace that was give:

> SQLsafe Backup and Recovery CLI Version 8.0.0.423 (x64)
>   13:37:14Info
>   Copyright (c) 2004-2014 Idera, Inc., All Rights Reserved.
>   13:37:14Info
>   http://www.idera.com/ 13:37:14Info
>
> Connecting to service on P02W02ETLDZZ017...success.  (8.0.0.423)
>   13:37:14Info
>   RESTORE KbbVehicle...FAILED.   13:37:14Info
>   Server instance: P02W02ETLDZZ017, Database: KBBVehicle 13:37:14Info
>
> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>
> Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
>   13:37:14Info
>   --- End of SQLsafeCmd output ---
>   13:37:14Info
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   13:37:14Info
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>   13:37:14Info
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>   13:37:14Info
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout)
>   13:37:14Info
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>   13:37:14Info
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   13:37:14Info
>      at Submission#0..ctor(Session session, Object& submissionResult)

Here is C# code (this is a snippet, this was actually running on octopus tentacle, but tried on Visual Studio.. same error):

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data;

String query = Octopus.Parameters["Octopus.Action[Create RESTORE T-SQL statement based on the given variable(s)].Output.MySqlTextMaster"];
String TargetServer = Octopus.Parameters["Octopus.Action[Constructs the target TargetServer and TargetDatabase variables].Output.TargetServer"];
String TargetDatabase = Octopus.Parameters["Octopus.Action[Constructs the target TargetServer and TargetDatabase variables].Output.TargetDatabase"];

StringBuilder connectionString = new StringBuilder();
connectionString.Append("Server=").Append(TargetServer).Append(";")
        .Append("Database=").Append(TargetDatabase).Append(";")
        .Append("Trusted_Connection=True;connection timeout= 1200;");

Console.WriteLine(connectionString.ToString());

try
{            
    using (SqlConnection connection = new    SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString()))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        command.CommandTimeout = 3600;
        //command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        connection.Open();
        connection.InfoMessage += (object obj, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e) => { System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message); };

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
}
```

Comment: How much time does it take when executing on SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: it takes 43 seconds.

Comment: I believe the default `CommandTimeout` on a `SqlCommand` is 30 seconds.

Comment: To what value have you set `CommmandTimeout`? Also could you provide C# code executing the sql command?

Comment: yes Ive set both connection timeout to an hour in connection string, also set commandTimeout in sqlCommand to an hour. it gaves the same result

Comment: posted code.. hope it helps

Comment: So just to confirm... does it throw the error after 30 seconds? It would seem that `command.CommandTimeout = 0;` is being ignored for some reason.

Comment: Hi Nick, I've tried to set it to 3600 and it still gives error. The reason why its 0 here is because ive just been testing diff values.

Comment: I'm trying to establish whether it is ignoring the setting or not. Is it throwing the error after 30 seconds no matter what you set it to? That tells us that it is ignoring your setting and that is where we need to look. It looks like there are a lot of reasons it might ignore it.

Comment: It's actually taking more than 1 min. Definitely longer than 30 seconds

Comment: So it seems there is no correlation between `CommandTimeout` and the time before the timeout error is thrown? From what you've explained, you've tried various timeouts, but regardless your command always throws a timeout error sometime after 30 seconds but before the thing actually completes?. In SSMS it takes 43 seconds but in your app it takes longer and throws a timeout. Sorry I'm kind out of ideas now. Maybe it's because Idera is in the mix. There's a lot of components at play here

Comment: I believe in Octopus there is a delay... but I'm starting to believe that maybe the timeout value is being ignored. However, I have several other steps uses similar code structure, the only difference is the query string... This is the only one that gives me timeout error. What could have cause the time out being ignored??